# 3D mesh to particle cloud conversion

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, particles

I need to convert arbitrary triangulated 3D mesh to cloud of particles that are uniformly spaced.
First thought was to try find a way to fill one 3D triangle. And then fill each triangle of mesh, removing duplicated particles on edges, but that's just hard and too much work. I was hoping for some more-math way.

Can anyone point me to an algorithm which can help me do my task correctly... well, at least approximatively?

Thanks

Comment: If you would be satisfied with particles that are uniformly distributed (as opposed to uniformly spaced) you could build on triangle sampling algorithms such as http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrianglePointPicking.html.  But it looks from your self-answer that you want uniformly spaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main options:

- Voxelization of mesh. Easy to implement the conversion of mesh to voxels, but it's inaccurate since uniform spacing cannot be achieved: distance between cubes can be x, x*sqrt(2) or x*sqrt(3) depending if neighbor cubes are in same plane and adjacent.
- Poisson disk sampling on surface. Hard to implement and lack of research material and code, but mathematically very correct. Some links:

  http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=135760

  http://web.mysites.ntu.edu.sg/cwfu/public/Shared%20Documents/dualtiling/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the TIN to raster using a GIS package or software such as R, then retrieve one point at the center of each pixel representing the value. (Example in [ArcGIS](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=TIN_to_Raster_%283D_Analyst%29))

EDIT: If the irregular 3D mesh has multiple heights per {x, y} a similar approach would be to sample the mesh using a voxel "grid" and keep one value per voxel. GRASS GIS has the [functionality](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/raster3dintro.html) to take the vertices of the TIN (3d mesh) and convert them to voxels, then back to a regular 3d cloud.

Comment: @J.B.: I'm suggesting that you then convert that "heightmap" back to a regular 3d mesh by extracting the value of each pixel and using it as a z value.

Comment: But for regular 3D mesh - one pair {x,y} can have multiple z values, thus this is not for complex 3D shapes to 3D point cloud conversion I need. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @J.B.: I might have misinterpreted your question. I was thinking in terms of terrain surface, but it seems you are dealing with some sort of 3D object with multiple heights at the same {x,y}? If so, there might be a similar solution using voxels to sample the mesh and return a point per voxel.

Comment: Correct, I was thinking of arbitrary 3D mesh (concave, convex, whatever). Voxels you say... that's a nice idea, I'll check it out.

Comment: I have just analyzed the solution. Voxelization will yield errors - particles wont be uniformly spaced. This is because distance between cube centers in the same plane is 'a', and between two diagonal neighbor cubes 'a*sqrt(3)=a*1.73', which yields great local errors (for example imagine voxelizing simple slope).

Comment: Won't all regular 3D meshes do that? In any case, you can always reduce the voxel size to a point where this "error" is acceptable. This is no different then the 2D case.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping there could be other algos, not grid-based, that would be more correct. But I guess I will have to stick with voxels i.e. uniform grid.